# NodeJs + Nginx .. upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header fro m upstream

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

My website was running on port 80 (http) and I was using nginx without any problem. Below is default file that I was using in nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Now I am planning to use https and downloaded Lets encrypt certs.Currently I am not able to access the website. I am getting following error .

***[error] 754#754: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header fro
m upstream, client: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "h
ttp://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "www.exapmple.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/"***

Below is my default file from nginx

```
# HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # certs sent to the client in SERVER HELLO are concatenated in ssl_certificate
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;


    # intermediate configuration. tweak to your needs.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    # OCSP Stapling ---
    # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

My nodejs code is as follows

```
var app = express();
 var port = 3000;
var server = https.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Application connected on port " + port);
});
```

and server is running at port 3000.

Thanks in advance.. J

Answer (score 12):

This issue is resolved now. Problem was with nodejs code.

I changed above code to

```
var app = express();
 var port = 3000;
var server = app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Application connected on port " + port);
});
```

https.createserver calls the http.server() internally and creates the instance.
so by removing this, the error got resolved.

Thanks for help !!

Comment: how did you pass in you ssl certificates, i am stuck here too

Comment: how did you pass in your ssl certificates, i am stuck here too          
   in my case this is how i passed in my own so if i tweak my code to yours it means i wont be aable to pass in options object where my ssl certificates are      https.createServer(options, app).listen(5000);

Comment: where exactly do you add this code lines. My server is located remote.

Answer (score 0):

this reason is because you request url has space, "h ttp://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico",and node http server doesn't support url has uncoded space,so you may delete the space or use net server instead. wish to solve you problem

Answer (score 0):

Set keepAliveTimeout to server

```js
server.keepAliveTimeout = 65000;
```

You can view this document: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/http.html#serverkeepalivetimeout, the keepalivetimeout of Node Server is default 5s, nginx is 60s. You can set `server.keepalivetimeout` to 65s to ensure that nginx closes the connection earlier than server